# Python '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

Tags: python

Can anyone help me please? I am getting this error:

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

My code is not finished trying to run a few tests and I can't get past this step:

```
# if it was to cold in the office remove number from list.
    if input < 16:
         total= len - 1
```

full code (so far here):

```
#Ask for temperature
print ("please enter the temperature")

Temp1 = input("enter temp: ")

Temp2 = input("enter temp: ")

Temp3 = input("enter temp: ")

Temp4 = input("enter temp: ")

Temp5 = input("enter temp: ")

Temp6 = input("enter temp: ")

Temp7 = input("enter temp: ")

Temp8 = input("enter temp: ")


#compute length of the list
length = len(Temp1+Temp2+Temp3+Temp4+Temp5+Temp6+Temp7+Temp8)

# if it was to cold in the office remove number from list.
if input < 16:
     total= len - 1 

#Calculate the percentage
percent= (len/total) * 100

#display the percentage the office was warm enough for the day
print percent here
```

Comment: The error says it all: `input` is a function, but you're trying to use it as an integer variable. Also, you'll get the same problem when you do `len - 1`: `len` is a built-in function, but you seem to also be trying to use it as a variable

Comment: `input` is still the function you used just before to get user-input.

Comment: And you have the same problem on the next line: `len` is also a builtin function.

Comment: Please work through a tutorial on Python `list`s.  You will need to put all of those values into some sort of sequence (such as a list) and iterate through that list.  See the `for` statement for doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
temperatures = []
userIn = "placeholder"
while userIn != "": # we're doing what you were with your input, but now the user can input as many as is needed, being able to press enter without input to continue
    userIn = float(input("Please enter the temperature. > ")) # I'm forcing float here as some people do record to one or two decimals. It also works for integers, too. It'll lead to a decimal in the final answer, though.
    temperatures.append(userIn)

for item in temperatures: # Here, we're doing the check for being too cold.
    if item < 16:
        temperatures.remove(temperatures.index(item)) # This looks a little wonky, but it works.

average = 0
for item in temperatures: # This is needed due to the flexible length of the list of temperatures.
    average += item

print("Average temp is "+str((average/len(temperatures))*100)) # I'd do the calculation in this statement, but you can do it beforehand if you want.
```